# Load *.dylib or *.so into the V8 Javascript runtime?

Tags: v8, shared-objects, frida

While not specifically related to Frida's use of V8, I was reading [this](https://frida.re/news/2019/09/18/frida-12-7-released/) Frida release page and noticed it made the following reference:

> Short of writing the whole agent in C, one could go ahead and build a
>   native library, and load it using Module.load(). This works but means
>   it has to be compiled for every single architecture, deployed to the
>   target, etc.

The comment by Ole alludes to this being possible, though I can't find any references other than the [NodeJS C++ Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world) features that are, of course, specific to NodeJS (though NodeJS does use V8).

---

**tl;dr**
How does one load a generic object such that all of its exported functions are callable from Javascript? Is this possible?

Comment: maybe @jmrk can answer this question

Comment: @Ifaruki Thanks for the link, though I found the reference. It's a Frida-api, not a v8 one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misinterpreting the context of the comment in the original link, it seems. I was under the impression that `Module.load` was a v8-ism, while it in fact appears to be a Frida-API.

https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#module

I figured this out about the time I was writing code to use `Module.getExportByName` to just pass the addresses of `dlopen` and `dlsym` to the entry of my CModule code.